# Complex plane (Show that triangle is right-angled)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

The points $O$,$P$ and $Q$ in the complex plane represent the complex numbers $0+0i$, $4+2i$ and $3-i$ respectively. Find the exact length of $PQ$ and hence, or otherwise, show that triangle $OPQ$ is right angled.

I found the distance of PQ is $\sqrt{10}$.

How to show that triangle $OPQ$ is right angled ?

Comment: Use Pythagoras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pythagoras. Check that $OP^2 = OQ^2 + PQ^2$.

[image]

Comment: Can I know what program you used to plot?

Comment: Plotted in LaTeX using the Tikz package.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to show that the angle $OQP$ is right.

Hint: make a sketch of the situation by drawing the points in the complex plane. It will then be clear how to apply Pythagoras.

This is another way of solving the problem:

If you set $s:=(-Q)/(P-Q)$ then you will find that $s$ is nonzero and purely imaginary. In polar coordinates the angle must be $90$ or $270$ degrees. Hence the angle is right.

Answer (score 1):

Segment $OQ$ is the vector $Q-O = (3,-1)$ and segment $QP$ is the vector $P-Q = (1,3)$. The dot product of these two vectors is $(3,-1)\cdot(1,3) = 3\cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot 3 = 0$, which means they are perpendicular.